# Change Text in dynamically added Row

Tags: android, textview, tablerow, android-tablelayout

iam realy new in Android and got some question:

I have some TableLayout, in this i want to add some rows dynamically. The rows have to look the same, so i wrote a template in xml and add this as view to the row.

In this xml file, there are some TextViews, and now i want to change the Text of these TextViews in every TableRow, so that every table row got some other text, like Sunday, Monday etc.

Later i want to add this Text from an array.

The TableLayoute xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/SPone_RL1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

 <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_ImageView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:contentDescription="@drawable/logo"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/SPoneTable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip" android:stretchColumns="*">

        </TableLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Row xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Sonntag"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="25.08.2013"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="15:00"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL2"
             >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="FC Bergalingen - FC Binzgen I"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/SPone_RL_SV_RL_RL_LL3"
             >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0:6"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

The Java Code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fcbonespielplan);


    /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.SPoneTable);


    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        /* Create a new row to be added. */
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        /* Create a View to be the row-content. */
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                //das Layout das 10 mal rein soll
                ViewGroup yourview = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spielplantablerow, null);



        /* Add View to row. */
        tr.addView(yourview);
        /* Add row to TableLayout. */
        tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baggroundtable);
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));





    }
}
```

Can anybody help me how i can set every time an other text to, maybe one of the TextViews? Without generate the whole TextView from the Java?

Comment: So this is your code. What does not work as expected? What do you get instead? What exactly is your question here?

Comment: There is no way to have a dynamic input to a TextView from the .xml layout file. You have to do it in your java code. just use .setText. And i do not quite get your problem, why would you want to have it in your .xml file? if you create your rows dynamically, you can easily add this one line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get a reference to the TextView and edit the text like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) yourview.findViewById(R.id.textViewID); // if your TextView is in yourview. If not, change it.
tv.setText("Your text or text resource");
```

Comment: Good luck with your soccer team ;-)